# how to use cURL API, from a video host 'MyStream.to' in PHP

Tags: php, api, curl, php-curl

how to use cURL API, from a video host 'MyStream.to'
in php! 
[API DOCUMENTATION FOR MyStream.to](https://api-docs.mystream.to/#retrieve-files)

> 1 This is the code that the documentation shows me :

```
curl "https://api.mystream.to/v1/files/:page" -H "Authorization: ACCESS_TOKEN" -D
```

> 2 I also tried (https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/) it does not
>   work "for me" :
>    (of course I replaced ACCESS TOKEN with my personal API key.)

```
<?php
// Generated by curl-to-PHP: http://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.mystream.to/v1/account- 
information');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');


$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: ACCESS_TOKEN';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

**nothing is displayed with this php code**

Comment: _“does not work”_ is anything but a useful problem description. Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Please show the code you have tried so far. There could be any number of pieces that would prevent it from working. Without sample code, we'd only be guessing.

Comment: I add the code I use with php !

Comment: Of course I replaced ACCESS TOKEN with my personal API key, from the beginning , it does not work ! blank page

Comment: The only echo I see is if there is an error :) Try ```$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    echo $result;
}```

Comment: @David It works perfectly, thank you , you can write an answer for me to validate for people who are the same problem as me :) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, there are no bugs here :)

However the only `echo()` statement I see is if there is an error. Otherwise no output is made!

Try:

```
if (curl_errno($ch)) { 
  echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch); 
} else { 
  echo $result; 
}
```